# Count of no of record returned, without considering Limit cakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, pagination

I want the no of records available in the database for the current query but without considering the LIMIT.

```
$this->Orders->find('all')
             ->where(['order_quantity']=>5)
             ->LIMIT(5);
```

Let's consider, I have 50 no of records for this above query. So just want the no of records available for the current query. I can't use 'count()' because of the limit it will always return total no of records available is less than or equal to 5. Is there any solution in cakePHP.

Comment: I assume that you haven't actually tried it? [**Counting**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#returning-the-total-count-of-records) ignores limit, offset, etc, and query objects remain useable, as counting internally uses a copy of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page in the CakePHP 3 book](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#returning-the-total-count-of-records), explains EXACTLY the answer to your question including how and why it works:

> **Returning the Total Count of Records**
>
> Using a single query object, it is possible to obtain the total number
>   of rows found for a set of conditions:
>
> ```
> $total = $articles->find()->where(['is_active' => true])->count();
> ```
>
> The count() method will ignore the limit, offset and page clauses,
>   thus the following will return the same result:
>
> ```
> $total = $articles->find()->where(['is_active' => true])->limit(10)->count();
> ```
>
> This is useful when you need to know the total result set size in
>   advance, without having to construct another Query object. Likewise,
>   all result formatting and map-reduce routines are ignored when using
>   the count() method.

Notice the bit about "... will ignore the limit, offset, and page clauses"

So try something like this:

```
$data = $articles->find()->where(['is_active' => true])->limit(10);
$count = $data->count();
```

Comment: I can also call the count() on the $total to get the same result. Actually, I want the no of record's available for the current query. Consider I have 50 results for the current query and I want to display 5 records in each page, and I want to display the user that "This is 5 from a total of 50." Hope you will get my point. @Rik.esh

Comment: I believe what I provided (from the book) does exactly what you asked, and are now explaining again.

Comment: Thanks, @Dave. It is only returning only the count, but I want count and result_rows, So is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are familiar with the use of limit in find. So, I suggest you to study the [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html).

The limit in your query means that the query will only display first 5 data even if the query actually has 50 data.

So, in order to get the actual data, you just need to remove the limit and make some changes in your code as follows:

```
$this->Orders->find('count')->where(['order_quantity' => 5]);
```

Comment: I want only 5 records from the 50 but I want to display the user that this is "50 RECORDS MATCHED, DISPLAYING ONLY 5". @Dave